# Cannot login to amAdmin Account in OPEN AM after kerberos setup

Tags: kerberos, openam

After setting up Windows SSO authentication using kerberos and OPEN AM.. When i tried to log into my default Admin Page of OPEN AM using Username: amAdmin and my default password  which i have given during the installation of OPEN AM in Windows Server 2008 R2, the main Login page of OPEN AM is Telling me the amAdmin Password is invalid and fails (Username or password invalid and sometimes Bad request error) open the main console page of OPEN AM Please HELP!

Answer (score 2):

Try appending module=DataStore to the login url